# Leer JSON con su formato Java

Tags: json, jsonobject

Bueno pues estoy intentando leer de una URL que responde con formato JSON el problema es que cuando lo imprimo por pantalla aparece escrito todo en una linea en vez de en su formato JSON es decir

Esto es lo que me aparece:

```
{"data":[{"page_id":"214605018563667","spend":{"lower_bound":"0","upper_bound":"99"},"id":"166493798118028","funding_entity":"PSOE Jaén"}.... etc
```

Cuando lo deseado es que se imprima asi:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
    "page_id": "214605018563667",
    "funding_entity": "PSOE Jaén",
  "spend": {
    "lower_bound": "0",
    "upper_bound": "99"
  },
  "id": "166493798118028"
},
{
  "page_id": "347210959259292",
  "funding_entity": "psoellanes",
  "spend": {
    "lower_bound": "0",
    "upper_bound": "99"
  },
  "id": "1457398084422641"
```

}

Este es mi codigo:

```
URL url = new URL( "Required URL" );
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

//[HTTP/1.1 200 OK] HTTP request succeeded
 if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200){
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = br.read()) != -1){
           sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(output);
        System.out.println(jObject);
```

Comment: Puedes  hacer uso de la librería `Gson`, que tiene métodos para embellecer (beautify) los objetos JSON (ver un [ejemplo aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310424/5587982)). O puedes usar también la típica librería `Jackson`, que tiene sus propios métodos para embellecer los JSON (ver un [ejemplo aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14532435/5587982)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola inténtelo de esta manera, el Api de JSONObject tiene un método para darle formato al json como puede ver en el link: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#toString(int)
solo debe cambiar la última línea:

```
URL url = new URL( "Required URL" );
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

//[HTTP/1.1 200 OK] HTTP request succeeded
 if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200){
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = br.read()) != -1){
           sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(output);
        System.out.println(jObject.toString(4));
```